# I'm using RxJava2 Disposable to observe clicks from button, how to change so that it does not add to CompositeDisposable each click (see code)?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

So say in my app I have a SignInUserActivity. I have an API that allows the user to sign in, which returns a Single (RxJava 2) from `signInUser()`. I use the MVVM pattern so the following `onClick` method gets called each time I click the button with id `button_sign_in_with_email`.

I'm using `CompositeDisposable` to add and dispose of disposables.
I think the following code is wrong because it's adding a new `Disposable` each time I click the sign in button, when really I just want ONE disposable Single that returns a response each time I click sign in button, either "sign in FAILED" (in which a Toast will be shown and the Disposable will continue to observe the sign in button for future clicks) and "sign in SUCCESS" (in which the SignInUserActivity will have an `Intent` to MainActivity, thus calling `onDestroy` on SignInUserActivity, thus clearing disposables from `CompositeDisposable`.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    mViewModel.clearDisposables();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And here is the onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_sign_in_with_email:
            Disposable disposable = signInUser() // get response observable
                    .subscribe((Response<SignInUserResponseBody> response) -> {         // subscribe to observable as disposable
                        if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful()) {       // verify that response was successful
                            String signedInUserId = response.body().getUserId();
                            if (signedInUserId != null) {                               // verify that user id exists in SignInUserResponseBody
                                boolean signInSuccessful = handleSignIn(signedInUserId, response.headers());     // save new user's credentials in realm
                                if (signInSuccessful) {                                            // successfully save new user's credentials
                                    ((SignInUserActivity) view.getContext()).onSignInSuccessful();
                                } else {
                                    ((SignInUserActivity) view.getContext()).onSignInFailed(view.getContext().getString(R.string.error_network_connectivity));                                 // error with saving to realm
                                }
                            } else {
                                ((SignInUserActivity) view.getContext()).onSignInFailed(response.body().getErrorMessage());                                                  // error with user input
                            }
                        } else {
                            ((SignInUserActivity) view.getContext()).onSignInFailed(view.getContext().getString(R.string.error_network_connectivity));                                         // bad response from SkoolarService
                        }
                    }, (Throwable ex) -> {
                        onSignInFailed(view.getContext(), ex.getMessage());
                    });
            addDisposable(disposable);
            break;
```

So how do I fix it so I don't always add a disposable when I click?

Answer (score 0):

Since your using a **Single** observable you don't have to dispose them manually. They get automatically disposed on **Success** or on **Error**. So you can remove the **CompositeDisposable** and call just subscribe on the single.

[Refer RxJava reference](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, adding `Disposable`s to `CompositeDisposable` over time should not cause any trouble, however, if you want to avoid the chance of leaking completely, you have to remove the `Disposable` when the flow terminates. This can get complicated so there is an [extensions project consumer](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#subscribeautorelease) that removes the `Disposable` automatically upon termination:

```
// compile "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.18.5"

CompositeDisposable composite = new CompositeDisposable();

Disposable d = SingleConsumers.subscribeAutoRelease(
    Single.just(1), composite,
    System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("Done")
);

assertEquals(0, composite.size());
```